# Is there an easy way to determine what page in a tab is open to read the table in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a tab control for payments. There is a separate page for Current, Future and Past payments each tab has a table that has a common field called ID.

I have a button that opens another form with more detailed info on the payment and uses the ID in a query to get the data.

Since each page uses/has the same ID is there an easy way to look up the ID regardless of which page is open?

I tried

```
ID = Forms!TabBills.Pages(TabBills.Value)![ID].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Tab control and its pages are irrelevant when referencing controls that sit on each page. Need to know the subform container name.

Value of tab control is index of page with focus. So use that value with Pages collection to grab Caption of that page. Assuming each tab control page has subform container control with a form as SourceObject and page Caption is same as name of subform container on that page consider:

```
strSubform = Me.TabBills.Pages(Me.TabBills.Value).Caption
intID = Me(strSubform)!ID
```

Any variation in naming may need `If Then Else` or `Select Case` structure.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a more dynamic approach.

> Helping procedure

This procedure tries to find a sub form control in a page.

If there are more then one sub form controls in a page it returns the first found.

```vb
Private Function FindSubformControlInPage(ByVal pageToCheck As Page) As SubForm
    Dim item As Control
    For Each item In pageToCheck.Controls
        If TypeOf item Is SubForm Then
            Set FindSubformControlInPage = item
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

> Usage

```vb
Dim currentSubformControl As SubForm
Set currentSubformControl = FindSubformControlInPage(Me.TabBills.Pages(Me.TabBills.Value))

If currentSubformControl Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No subform control in the current page"
    Exit Sub
End If

If currentSubformControl.SourceObject = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "The current subform control doesn't contain a form."
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim currentSubform As Form
Set currentSubform = currentSubformControl.Form

MsgBox "Found subform: " & currentSubform.Name
```

> More compact usage

That means you're sure that there always is a sub form control and it contains a form.

```vb
Dim currentSubform As Form
Set currentSubform = FindSubformControlInPage(Me.TabBills.Pages(Me.TabBills.Value)).Form

MsgBox "Found subform: " & currentSubform.Name
```

> Get the ID

Finally, having the correct (sub-)form you can access your `ID` field:

```vb
Dim currentID As Long
currentID = currentSubform.Controls("ID").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

Have a function to look up the ID and call this from your button:

```vb
Private Sub YourButton_Click()

    MsgBox GetCurrentID()

End Sub


Public Function GetCurrentID() As Long

    Dim Control     As Control
    Dim CurrentID   As Long

    For Each Control In Me!YourTabControl.Pages(Me!YourTabControl.Value).Controls
        If Control.ControlType = acSubform Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not Control Is Nothing Then
        CurrentID = Nz(Control.Form!ID1.Value)
    End If

    GetCurrentID = CurrentID

End Function
```